# See last modification of variables in Pycharm Debugging session

Tags: debugging, pycharm

I am using Pycharm to debug my python code.

Is there any way, when stopped at a breakpoint, to see not just the values of the variables, but also what instruction/function set that value?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware. You'd have to set an earlier breakpoint and see.